# After finding the right document, how do I query the object with the right date and update it in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a heatmap using react-d3-heatmap and it needs data as [{date: Date, count: Number}].

This is my model.

```
const HeatMapSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    data: [{
        date: { 
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        count: { 
            type: Number,
            default: 0
         },
    }]
})
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways to query the document that pertains to the correct user and then go into the data to query the date and increment the count. I installed moment.js to help query the date. Can you help me find the model matching the user and update the count for that day within the data object? Thanks

```
import HeatMap from '../models/heatmap.model'
import errorHandler from './../helpers/dbErrorHandler'
import moment from 'moment'    
const addDate = async (req, res) => {
      const id = '60e88ceaa331a63d2c9523fc'
      const today = moment().startOf('day')
      try {
        let data = await HeatMap
          .find({user: id})
          .updateOne({data: {date: {$gte: today.toDate(), $lte: moment(today).endOf('day').toDate()}}}, {count: 1})
        res.json(data)
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        })
      }
    }

export default {
    create,
    getHeatMapData,
    addDate  
}
```

found a way.

```
const addDate = async (req, res) => {
  const id = '60e88ceaa331a63d2c9523fc'
  const today = moment().startOf('day')
  try {
    const query = { user: id, "data.date": {
      $gte: today.toDate(),
      $lte: moment(today).endOf('day').toDate()}
    }
    const updateDocument = {
      $inc: { "data.$.count": 1 }
    };
    let data = await HeatMap.find({$and: [
      {user: id}, {"data": {$gte: today.toDate()}}
    ]})
    if (data.length === 0) {
      await HeatMap.updateOne({user: id}, {"$push": {"data": {'count': 0}}})
    } else {
      data = await HeatMap.updateOne(query, updateDocument)
    }
    res.json(data)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in updateOne use this :

```
updateOne({$set:{"data.$[elem].count": 1}},
{$arrayFilters:[{"elem.date": {$gte: today.toDate(), $lte: moment(today).endOf('day').toDate()}}]})
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but after creating a new doc so that it can be fit the $gte: today.toDate(), I still get the same response. { "ok: 0, "n": 0, "nModified": 0}

Comment: Could you log today.toDate()